# Getting error while running someone else project's react native code in VS code

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native, I am getting error while trying to run someone else project in my VS code.

Steps that i followed:

1. Unzipped project
2. Kept in one folder
3. Opened that project in VS Code
4. Run command npm install

Can someone please help me what should i do.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XeZy.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Have a look on the bellow solution. Also you can try yarn.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74056696/npm-err-could-not-resolve-error-while-using-npx-react-native-init